# How do I replace multiple value in a word

Tags: java

I have a project to replace the letters b and i in a word.  The word is "big" it contains both letters.  and I have to replace it with the letters.  b  with fin and i with boot.  If I replace it in my array the i gets replaced  so I end up with "fbootnbootn"  as the i in fin is replaced.

Or the way I have it in my code now is the b is replaced in the new string and the i is replaced in the other string.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Crypto {

    public String org;
    public String sb;


    public String encrypt(String org){

        int index1=-1;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(org);
        System.out.println ("here is org "+org);
        String s1[] = new String[100];

        while (sc.hasNext())
        {
            index1++;
            s1[index1] = sc.nextLine( );
            System.out.println(s1[index1]);
        }
        for (int j=0; j <=index1; j++)
        {
        String NewString="";
        System.out.println("array "+ s1[j]);
        Scanner sc2= new Scanner (s1[j]);

        while (sc2.hasNextLine())
            {
            String[] split =sc2.nextLine().split(" ");
            int ding=0;
            for (int k=0; k<(split.length); k++)
            {

                if (split[ding].contains("v"))
                {
                String nw=split[ding].replace ("v", "ag,r");
                NewString = NewString +" "+ nw;
                System.out.println(split[ding] + "  " +NewString);  
                }
                if (split[ding].contains("m"))
                {
                String nw=split[ding].replace ("m", "ssad");
                NewString = NewString +" "+ nw;
                System.out.println(split[ding] + "  " +NewString);
                }
                if (split[ding].contains("g"))
                {
                String nw=split[ding].replace ("i", "boot");
                NewString = NewString +" "+ nw;
                System.out.println(split[ding] + "  " +NewString);
                }
                if (split[ding].contains("b"))
                {
                String nw=split[ding].replace ("b", "fin");
                NewString = NewString +" "+ nw;
                System.out.println(split[ding] + "  " +NewString);
                }
                ding++;
            //NewString=NewString+" ";


            org=NewString;
            }
            }

    }

        return org;
}
}
```

Comment: For each word, step through each letter and test whether it should be replaced, then add either the original letter or the replacement to `newString` (variable names should begin with a lowercase letter to distinguish them from class names).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public String myreplace(String s) {
    String r = "";
    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == 'b') {
            r = r + "fin";
        } else (s.charAt(i) == 'i') {
            r = r + "boot";
        } else {
            r = r + s.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return r; 
}
```

code not compiled, but you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

You are drastically overcomplicating things. A String practically is an array of characters, so you can loop through a String. Then, check if the next character is either a b or an i, and if so, add the wanted replacement to the result. Else, just add the character that is at that index.

```
public class ReplaceLetters {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        String original = "big";
        String bReplacement = "fin";
        String iReplacement = "boot";
        String res = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < original.length();i++) {
            if (original.charAt(i) == 'b')
                res += bReplacement;
            else if (original.charAt(i) == 'i')
                res += iReplacement;
            else
                res += original.charAt(i);
        }

        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered find/replace using regular expressions? If not, you should check this out: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html. If that doesn't help, then you can try manipulating String character by character.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like below:

I program in both C# and Java so if I've mixed up a few syntax, please ignore it. But use a StringBuilder and keep adding to it if it needs replacement.. In the default switch just add whatever was passed in.

```
public string encrypt(String word)
{
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     for(int i = 0; i < word.length; i++)
     {
        switch(word.charAt(i).ToLower())
        {
            case 'b' : 
             sb.Append("fin");
             break;
            ....
            default :
            sb.Append(word.charAt(i));

        }
     }

      return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is similar to swapping values between two columns in a DB, you need a third variable here.  Here's is an example:

```
// string not present in your input text
String unusedString = "~~~~";
// replace "i" with the special character, output "b~~~~g"
String temp = "big".replaceAll("i", unusedString);
System.out.println(temp);
// replace "b" with "fin", output "fin~~~~g"
temp = temp.replaceAll("b", "fin");
System.out.println(temp);
// replace special character (just the old "i"s) with "boot", output "finbootg"
temp = temp.replaceAll(unusedString, "boot");
```

Answer (score 0):

**`StringUtils.replaceEach`** in **Commons Lang** can be helpful.

```
public static String stringReplace(String inputString) {
    String[] searchArray = new String[]{"b", "i"};
    String[] replaceArray = new String[]{"fin", "boot"};
    return StringUtils.replaceEach(inputString, searchArray, replaceArray);

}
```

`Input`: big

`Output`: finbootg

`Input`: bbg

`Output`: finfing

`Input`: biib

`Output`: finbootbootfin

Comment: What's StringUtils fully qualified class name?

Comment: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils

You would need to have commons-lang.jar in your classpath.